# Magnet on a piezo - Can this oscillating field give me a radio transmitter?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics, radio, radio-frequency

I can read on wikipedia that radio waves are of frequency 3kHz-3THz.

I know that piezoelectric actuator can reach eg. 20 kHz.

What would happen if I put a small neodymium magnet on a piezoelectric actuator subjected to modulated 20kHz voltage? It would move the magnet and its magnetic field.

I know that if a magnetic field changes with time in a certain point - it creates an oscillating electric field, which also creates oscillating magnetic field. That yields radio waves.

If I put a radio receiver near such installation - would I be able to detect how is my piezo modulated by listening to the radio?

Comment: That frequency is very low, much lower than typical FM band signals, and several octaves below the AM band, so you won't detect it with a normal radio receiver. Also, I think the amount of power transmitted will be tiny since your oscillator is very small relative to the wavelength, which is just under 15 kilometres.